# Using classlibrary that extends strings in view for mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a classlibrary where I have extended string with some functions that returns email and url links and so on. And I have this in web.config

```
<add namespace="TestProject.Helpers" />
```

Somehow the extended functions doesnt show when I use them in razor views.

What might be wrong here? if I have them in controller with using-statement they work.

/Lasse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the namespace in web.config file located inside the views folder under `system.web.webPages.razor` section. If still there is no intellisense use the Razor's `@using <your extensions namespace>` inside the Razor view page.

Edit: Dont forgot to close and reopen the .cshtml for the intellisense to catch up.